# Magento 2 issue on category page and product page of "inventory_stock_1" table?

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, multi-source-inventory

I am facing issue on product page and category page.

[image]

Can any one suggest or guide me on this ?

Comment: Did you change  definer in database dump?

Comment: Have you recently moved server, have you connected your site correctly and run setup upgrade and redeployed your  site

Comment: @DavaGordon yes we switched the server.

Comment: @AdarshEdiyottil yes that's why it created issue. But i did not dump server team did. can you tell me that how definer change during db dump?

Comment: @CharulTyagi seems like an issue with your env config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found after debug and research we need to run query on database.

ALTER DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` VIEW inventory_stock_1 AS select distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,`product`.`sku` AS `sku` from (`db_name`.`cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status` join `db_name`.`catalog_product_entity` `product` on((`legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id`)));